# How to make a popup window to filter date for records which in listview

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a list of data which I'm retrieving from database and there is a column for date. So I just want to filter my records by date. So for that I created an option menu now my moto is that if I click that filter button any window should be appear or whatever which could make better filtration of my records. Please give me any clue or solution so that I can go ahead.
thanks.

WHAT LOGIC CODE CAN I PUT IN FILTER CASE TO POPUP A WINDOW TO FILTER DATE.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_menu,menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.action_filter:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Filter is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```